# Image Download Service excess resource usage

Tags: android, performance, android-service

I am working on an ImageDownloadService. The problem is that it downloads images from my app continuously and thus hangs my phone. I believe that my Download Service is using too much resources. I want my service to slow down if it crosses a certain RAM usage.
Can someone tell me how can I put a limit to resource usage?

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl));
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
String imageName = "IMAGE_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
File image = new File(directoryPath, imageName);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(image);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
is.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: Try using libraries like Glide to load images.

Comment: if you don't want to use third part libraries, you can use [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am downloading images using this and working fine.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // getting file length
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream to write file
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }
```